# phpmailer not redirecting when mail is sent

Tags: php, redirect, phpmailer

I am using phpmailer to send emails, when email is successfully sent then i want to redirect the page to other page, but it is not working.

I tried using server side redirect ie `header();` but it is not working.

when i try it for client side its perfectly redirect to other page.
And i have not used any `sessions` on this page or the other page.

below is the code what i have tried

```
if(!$mail->Send()){
 echo "Mailer Error: ". $mail->ErrorInfo;
}else{
 //echo "Message sent!";
 header('Location: contactus-thankyou.php');
 ?>
    <!-- <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=contactus-thankyou.php" /> -->
 <?php
}
```

Comment: @Bondye not working! still its not redirecting.

Comment: maybe 'else' block doesn't work.

Comment: so. please set error_reporting(E_ALL) and display_errors to 1. Maybe you have notices above.

Comment: @user900898 It working good, and it showing a message `Message sent`.. but its not reditecting.

Comment: @Rafee Add ob_clean() before line with header function call

Answer (score 5):

The solution is: put SMTPDebug value in 0.

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
```

Comment: This is the solution to the problem

Comment: This solves the problem. Any other values for SMTPDebug will echo to the browser and break the header. Thus you will not be able to redirect!

Answer (score 0):

try removing the space between `location and the url`

`header('Location:contactus-thankyou.php');`

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to redirect instead and it works.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       setTimeout(function(){
           location.href="../index.php";
       });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the output is getting buffered before the header loaction statement and header statement usually don't like echo or outputs from server before it.
just use `obs_start();` at the top and `obs_end_flush();` at the end :
example:

```
    obs_start();
    php mailer script starts.........
    ...
    obs_end_flush();
header("Location: index.php");
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use

```
echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>location.href='contactus-thankyou.php'</script>";
```

in place of

```
header('Location: contactus-thankyou.php');
```

Comment: I want to redirect the page with server side only.. not from client side

Comment: I want to tell you that, header is not working all time, In some servers we have to use this JS as alternative